# meaning of as in following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions, as

what's the meaning of "as" in the following sentence

> An awful way to finally unite Iraqis **as** they fight for their country's future to be in their own hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance the word "as" means "while", "concurrently" or "at the same time as".